# Can I automate files being added to my solution explorer in VS15?

Tags: visual-studio, automation

I'm working in Visual Studio 15, and have a project that constantly has assets being added to it. The problem is forgetting to add the new/updated assets to the solution and set up their properties each time one is added.

**Is there a way to have VS recursively check a certain directory for new/changed files, import them to the Solution Explorer, and change their build properties?**

The properties I'm referring to are "Build Action", "Copy to Output Directory", etc.